# How to load Google Ads with PageView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using `google_mobile_ads: ^0.12.1+1` for showing ads in my app. It's working fine in all places except in the `Scaffold bottomNavigationBar` which has a `PageView` in the body. Relevant code is -

```
class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Question> questions;

  QuizPage({Key key, this.questions}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  PageController controller;
  Question question;
  int currentPage = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = PageController();
    question = widget.questions.first;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: buildQuestionsBody(),
      bottomNavigationBar: loadAds(),
    );
  }

  Widget buildQuestionsBody() {
    return PageView.builder(
      onPageChanged: (index) => nextQuestion(index: index),
      controller: controller,
      itemCount: widget.questions.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          child: Center(
              child: Text(
            widget.questions[index].questionText,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          )),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget loadAds() {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      child: AdWidget(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        ad: AdMobService.createBannerAd()..load(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void nextQuestion({int index, bool jump = false}) {
    final nextPage = controller.page + 1;
    final indexPage = index ?? nextPage.toInt();

    setState(() {
      question = widget.questions[indexPage];
      currentPage = indexPage;
    });

    if (jump) {
      controller.jumpToPage(indexPage);
    }
  }
}
```

If I run the above code as such or shift `controller = PageController();` from `initState` to the top where I declare the variable, the ads load initially, but on changing pages they don't load, also the app freezes without giving any error.

If I remove `controller = PageController();` from `initState`, the ads load normally, and also on swiping pages change but now I get an error - **The getter 'page' was called on null.**

I am not able to find out the source of the error.

Edit 1 - After some more tries I found out that this conflict occurs whenever `setState()` is called for e.g. whenever I call `nextQuestion` in this code or other methods where `setState()` is called. Without google ads, `setState` works fine in all methods. So it seems now the question should be - **How to make google ads work with setState()?**

Comment: can you try https://pastebin.com/5ccgiQjc , if it works I will add that as an answer , acc to me problem is in using setState()

Comment: @AmanVerma yes, it looks like the problem in setState of `nextQuestion`. I tested your code. It showed error on `widget.questions[controller.page.round()].questionText`. The error was - `The following _CastError was thrown building: Null check operator used on a null value`. However it works when I changed `round()` to `toInt()` and also it would work even when I change to `widget.questions[index].questionText`. The problem arises when I use `onPageChanged: (index) => nextQuestion(index: index)`

Comment: @AmanVerma I tested and found out that it's indeed a problem with `setState`, as the issue arises in all the methods where I use `setState()`. Since `setState` is necessary for my methods, I don't think I can use ads on this page.

Comment: No setstate is not neccessory as per the code you have given , you can remove the onPageChanged Callback

Comment: I will add a answer that i have I tried and it will work

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this method and it works

```
class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Question> questions;

  QuizPage({Key key, @required this.questions}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  PageController _controller=PageController();
  List<Widget> _questions;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(widget.questions==null)
      _questions = <Widget>[Text("Alas! No questions RN")];
    else{
      _questions = widget.questions.map((e)=>Container(
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                  e.questionText,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )),
                              ))
                          .toList();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: Appbar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: buildQuestionsBody(),
      bottomNavigationBar: loadAds(),
    );
  }

  Widget buildQuestionsBody() {
    return PageView(
                      controller: _controller,
                      children: _questions);
  }

  Widget loadAds() {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      child: AdWidget(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        ad: AdMobService.createBannerAd()..load(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. like I mentioned in my edit 1, setState is required for code. What I mean by this is -  I have 3 places in my actual project where setState is required - 1. There are two buttons (next, prev) using nextQuestion method (sample code attached in question) 2. there is question numbers widget which also depend on nextQuestion method to directly move to specific question and lastly 3. on option clicked the colour of the background container changes to green or red depending on if option is correct answer or not (I didn't provide its code in question)

Comment: These all things can be achieved  without setState , for the next and prev use `_controller.nextPage()` and `_controller.previousPage()` , And for the jump feature that use `_controller.jumpToPage`   . If you could share complete code , I may be able to help

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your continuous help and sorry for the delay. I was trying to figure out to share code on github - https://github.com/atultiwari/ms

Comment: I have uploaded my entire project in the above-mentioned link. There are 3 files in particular - (1) ui/pages/quiz_page.dart => it has method - nextQuestion and selectOption  (line 180 & 191) which would require setState (2)ui/wiget/options_widget.dart => it has onClickedOption(option) and getColorForOption (line 33 & 88) & (3)question_number_widget.dart => buildNumber(index: index, isSelected: isSelected) (line 31)

Comment: I have mentioned the respective line numbers of the methods I am using and shared the whole project so that you can have a broader and better overall look. Thank you once again for your support